# Nuget can no longer search certain libraries/addons when Resharper is installed

Tags: resharper, nuget-package, resharper-9.0

I have a newly reformatted PC, I installed VS 2012. Then started a project. I searched and downloaded and installed JQuery, Knockoutjs, bootstrap and EntityFramework. All of these appeared on top of the list. Then I decided to install Resharper 9. Then I started a new project, then tried to reinstall the jquery, knockout and entityframework. But nuget can no longer search these libraries/addons. It was only when I installed resharper that this happened. I tried opening the old project which I previously installed the said libraries, and use nuget to see if those libraries can still be searched, but no longer appear on the list.

Do I have to turn off some feature of resharper or is this a permanent bug or con in installing resharper?